# how to show list of item in module param in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have one problem related to module param , what I need is to show list of title from my custom component to my custom module as parameters. I saw that thing in `mod_articles_popular` but not able to understand how that category get listed from com_category. Please help me to understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement is something like , getting some dynamic values in module param.

So this [link](http://docs.joomla.org/SQLMultiSelectX) will help you to solve the task.
This [one also similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424689/joomla-dynamic-dropdown-list-in-admin-panel)

something like below.

```
<param name="field-name" type="sqlmultilistx" sql="SELECT * FROM #__jos_mytable" key_field="id" value_field="name" default="OPT1"
multiple="multiple" label="Select one or more items" description="Use Ctrl-click to select more than one item.">
        <option value="-2">Title for option 1</option>
        <option value="-1">Title for option 2</option>
</param>
```

Hope its helps.